# How to write a efficient mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently doing a task which involves, writing some queries. The result which I want to fetch is,sort of looks like this, the attacker_king is like number of times attacked and defender_king number of time defended.

```
'most_active': {
            'attacker_king': null,
            'defender_king': null,
            'region': null,
            'name': null
        },
        'attacker_outcome': {
            'win': null,
            'loss': null
        } }
```

I have written my query in MongoDB, and it is like this

```
db.aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: "$attacker_king",
            "count": {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }},{
            $sort:{"count":-1}
        },{
            $limit:1
        }

    ], function (err, response) {
        result.most_active.attacker_king = response[0]._id;

        db.aggregate([
            {$group: {
                _id: "$defender_king",
                "count": {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }},{
                $sort:{"count":-1}
            },{
                $limit:1
            }

        ],function(err,response){
            result.most_active.defender_king = response[0]._id;
            db.aggregate([
                {$group: {
                    _id: "$region",
                    "count": {
                        $sum: 1
                    }
                }},{
                    $sort:{"count":-1}
                },{
                    $limit:1
                }
            ],function(err,response){
                result.most_active.region = response[0]._id;
                db.aggregate([
                    {$group: {
                        _id: "$name",
                        "count": {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }},{
                        $sort:{"count":-1}
                    },{
                        $limit:1
                    }
                ],function(err,response){
                    result.most_active.name = response[0]._id;
                    //return res.send(result)
                    db.aggregate([
                        {$group: {
                            _id: "$attacker_outcome",
                            "count": {
                                $sum: 1
                            }
                        }},{
                            $sort:{"count":-1}
                        }
                    ],function(err,response){
                        console.log(response)
                        result.attacker_outcome.win = response[0].count;
                        result.attacker_outcome.loss = response[1].count;
                        return res.send(result);
                    })
                })
            })  
        })
    })
```

As we can see the query have become pretty long and would be hard to debug, I think would be slow, can we optimize it? Can you at least point me in the right direction.
Thanks